Why is the UI not updated in the popup in Flutter?
I have a project where I manage state with provider. In this project, I want the color of the container selected in the popup to change, but the change is not instantaneous.
main.dart codes:
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:want_to_do/services/service.locator.dart';
import 'export.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
    const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  );
  await setupLocator();
  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [
        AppLocaleConstant.TR_LOCALE,
        AppLocaleConstant.EN_LOCALE,
      ],
      path: AppLocaleConstant.LANG_PATH,
      fallbackLocale: AppLocaleConstant.EN_LOCALE,
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => SettingsViewModel(),
          ),
        ],
        child: const MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      navigatorKey: locator<AppRoutes>().baseNavigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: Routes.generateRoute,
      initialRoute: Routes.MainTab,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      builder: (context, widget) {
        return widget!;
      },
    );
  }
}

CustomTaskPriority codes:
import 'package:want_to_do/export.dart';
import 'package:want_to_do/generated/locale_keys.g.dart';

class CustomTaskPriority extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onClickCancel;
  final VoidCallback onClickSave;
  final int selectedPriority;
  final ValueChanged<int> onPrioritySelected;
  const CustomTaskPriority({
    super.key,
    required this.onClickCancel,
    required this.onClickSave,
    required this.selectedPriority,
    required this.onPrioritySelected,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<int> priority = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
            child: Text(
              LocaleKeys.home_taskPriority.locale,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: AppColors.white.withOpacity(0.87),
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: CustomDivider(),
          ),
          Wrap(
            spacing: 16,
            runSpacing: 16,
            children: [
              ...priority.map((priority) {
                return _buildPriorityItem(
                  onTap: () => onPrioritySelected(priority),
                  isClick: selectedPriority == priority,
                  priority: priority,
                );
              }).toList(),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: CustomButton(
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.darkGrey,
                    title: LocaleKeys.cancel.locale,
                    titleColor: AppColors.lavenderBlue,
                    onClick: () => onClickCancel.call(),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(
                  child: CustomButton(
                    title: LocaleKeys.save.locale,
                    onClick: () => onClickSave.call(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPriorityItem({
    required int priority,
    required bool isClick,
    required VoidCallback onTap,
  }) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onTap.call(),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isClick ? AppColors.lavenderBlue : AppColors.balticSea,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              AppAssets.icFlagPath,
              width: 24,
              height: 24,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 6),
            Text(
              '${priority.toString()}',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: AppColors.white.withOpacity(0.87),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The area where I use the component MainTab codes:
import 'package:want_to_do/export.dart';
import 'package:want_to_do/generated/locale_keys.g.dart';
import 'package:want_to_do/ui/widgets/custom_task_priority.dart';

class MainTabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainTabPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainTabPage> createState() => _MainTabPageState();
}

class _MainTabPageState extends BaseStatefulState<MainTabPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _vm = Provider.of<MainTabViewModel>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
      extendBody: true,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showCustomBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            child: AddTaskBottomSheet(
              taskTitleController: _vm.taskTitleController,
              taskDescriptionController: _vm.taskDescriptionController,
              onclickTaskPriority: () {
                _vm.checkTaskParameters()
                    ? showPopupDialog(
                        context: context,
                        child: CustomTaskPriority(
                          onClickCancel: appRoutes.popIfBackStackNotEmpty,
                          onClickSave: appRoutes.popIfBackStackNotEmpty,
                          selectedPriority: _vm.selectedPriority,
                          onPrioritySelected: (int value) {
                            _vm.selectedPriority = value;
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    : showToastMessage(
                        LocaleKeys.errorMessages_emptyOrNotSame.locale,
                      );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        shape: CircleBorder(eccentricity: 1),
        child: _buildFloatingActionButton(),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        color: AppColors.darkGrey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
          child: _buildNavigationBar(_vm),
        ),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(_vm),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(MainTabViewModel vm) {
    switch (vm.currentIndex) {
      case 0:
        return HomeProvider();
      case 1:
        return CalendarProvider();
      case 2:
        return HomeProvider();
      case 3:
        return ProfileProvider();
      default:
        return HomeProvider();
    }
  }

  Widget _buildFloatingActionButton() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.lavenderBlue,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: Image.asset(AppAssets.icPlusAddPath),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNavigationBar(MainTabViewModel vm) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        BottomAppBarItem(
          iconAddress: vm.currentIndex == 0
              ? AppAssets.icActiveHomePath
              : AppAssets.icInactiveHomePath,
          pageName: LocaleKeys.home_home.locale,
          onTap: () {
            vm.currentIndex = 0;
          },
        ),
        BottomAppBarItem(
          iconAddress: vm.currentIndex == 1
              ? AppAssets.icActiveCalendarPath
              : AppAssets.icInactiveCalendarPath,
          pageName: LocaleKeys.calendar.locale,
          onTap: () {
            vm.currentIndex = 1;
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(),
        BottomAppBarItem(
          iconAddress: vm.currentIndex == 2
              ? AppAssets.icActiveFocusPath
              : AppAssets.icInactiveFocusPath,
          pageName: LocaleKeys.focus.locale,
          onTap: () {
            vm.currentIndex = 2;
          },
        ),
        BottomAppBarItem(
          iconAddress: vm.currentIndex == 3
              ? AppAssets.icActiveProfilePath
              : AppAssets.icInactiveProfilePath,
          pageName: LocaleKeys.profileTitle.locale,
          onTap: () {
            vm.currentIndex = 3;
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

MainTabViewModel codes:
import 'package:want_to_do/base/base_view_model.dart';
import 'package:want_to_do/export.dart';

class MainTabViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  TextEditingController taskTitleController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController taskDescriptionController = TextEditingController();

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  int get currentIndex => _currentIndex;

  set currentIndex(int value) {
    _currentIndex = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  int _selectedPriority = 1;

  int get selectedPriority => _selectedPriority;

  set selectedPriority(int value) {
    _selectedPriority = value;
    print("Priority changed: $value");
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String _taskTitleText = '';
  String _taskDescriptionText = '';

  set taskTitleText(String text) {
    _taskTitleText = text;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get taskTitleText => _taskTitleText;

  set taskDescriptionText(String text) {
    _taskDescriptionText = text;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get taskDescriptionText => _taskDescriptionText;

  bool checkTaskParameters() {
    _taskTitleText = taskTitleController.text;
    _taskDescriptionText = taskDescriptionController.text;
    if (_taskTitleText.isNotEmpty && _taskDescriptionText.isNotEmpty)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
}

MainTabProvider codes:
import 'package:want_to_do/export.dart';

class MainTabProvider extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainTabProvider({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MainTabViewModel(),
      child: const MainTabPage(),
    );
  }
}

BaseStatfulState codes:
import 'package:want_to_do/export.dart';
import 'package:want_to_do/services/service.locator.dart';
import 'package:want_to_do/utils/utility.dart';

abstract class BaseStatefulState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State<T> {
  final AppRoutes appRoutes = locator<AppRoutes>();
  LocalStorageService localStorage = LocalStorageService();
  late FToast fToast;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fToast = FToast();
    fToast.init(context);
  }

  void showToastMessage(String content) {
    fToast.showToast(
      child: Utility().buildToast(content),
      gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
      positionedToastBuilder: (context, child) {
        return Positioned(
          child: child,
          top: 50,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void showCustomBottomSheet({
    required BuildContext context,
    required Widget child,
  }) {
    showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      builder: (context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void showPopupDialog({
    required BuildContext context,
    required Widget child,
  }) {
    showDialog<void>(
      barrierColor: AppColors.black.withOpacity(0.74),
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          ),
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: AppColors.darkGrey,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

BaseViewModel codes:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
class BaseViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {

}

The first screen that comes up when I click on the plus button:

When I click on someone on this screen, I want the color of the container I click to change.
This is the screen that appears when I click on the flag button:

Console output when I click on any of them:

Frankly, I do not want to use StatefulWidget in the component. I don't know how to fix this situation. What am I missing? I'm waiting for your ideas. Thanks in advance. I wrapped it with consumer but still nothing changed.

You can try with any statemanagement tools kike getx, bloc, reiverpod etc

first , the popup or the show dialog or the bottom-Sheet , should be a separate state (statefullWidget or statefulbuilder both give you SetState() function)
second, you should pass this SetState() function as parameter and call it from outside ,whenever you want to update this state UI.

My goal is to create my components without using statefulwidget and that's why I'm looking for a method other than setState.

you don't have to use statefulwidget ,there are widget called  statefulbuilder or use Provider State Management (update UI without states)
